# java JDBC/mysql - How to avoid Communication link failure

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to solve a recurrent error in a program :

> 2021-05-10 14:04:58,085 9282528 ERROR [DispatchThread: [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteSession[connectionId=414D51436D71747578202020202020208E4679605E23EC2F]]] com.arkea.methodes.jms.connection.AsyncJMSConsumer (onMessage()) | user: - FunctionalException : () - PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table WHERE field1 = ? AND field2 = ? AND field3 = ?]; Communications link failure

> Last packet sent to the server was 925624 ms ago.; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

> Last packet sent to the server was 925624 ms ago.

The program I am working on has configuration file :

```xml
    <bean id="DS.database" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>jdbc:mysql://linktodatabase?autoReconnect=true</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>username</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>password</value>
        </property>
        <!-- Le nombre initial de connexions qui sont creees quand le pool demarre -->
        <property name="initialSize">
            <value>1</value>
        </property>
        <!--
        Le nombre maximum de connexions actives qui sont allouees a ce pool a un
        instant donne. Mettre une valeur negative pour un nombre maximum illimite
         -->
        <property name="maxActive">
            <value>5</value>
        </property>
        <!-- 
        Le temps maximum en millisecondes que le pool attendra (quand aucune
        connexion n'est disponible) qu'une connexion soit retournee avant de
        generer une exception. Mettre la valeur a -1 pour un temps illimite.
         -->
        <property name="maxWait">
            <value>3000</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Despite several connection allowed by the configuration file, the error communication link failure come back a lot.

Somebody has an idea?

Comment: Apache Commons Pool isn't a great connection pool. I would switch to [Hikari](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP). Next, your connections are apparently being timed out from the server. You should check your mysql server configuration.

Comment: This usually means that your connection exceeded the maximum time configured in MySQL or the connection was otherwise terminated (some routers or firewall may reset a connection if it is idle for too long).